# mysql 4 vs mysql 5 error 1052 happens in mysql 4 only

Tags: mysql, sql

Tables:

```
mysql> describe phppos_sales_items_taxes;
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sale_id    | int(10)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| item_id    | int(10)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| line       | int(3)        | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| name       | varchar(255)  | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| percent    | decimal(15,3) | NO   | PRI | 0.000   |       |
| cumulative | int(1)        | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> describe phppos_sales_items;
+--------------------+----------------+------+-----+--------------+-------+
| Field              | Type           | Null | Key | Default      | Extra |
+--------------------+----------------+------+-----+--------------+-------+
| sale_id            | int(10)        | NO   | PRI | 0            |       |
| item_id            | int(10)        | NO   | PRI | 0            |       |
| description        | varchar(255)   | YES  |     | NULL         |       |
| serialnumber       | varchar(255)   | YES  |     | NULL         |       |
| line               | int(3)         | NO   | PRI | 0            |       |
| quantity_purchased | decimal(23,10) | NO   |     | 0.0000000000 |       |
| item_cost_price    | decimal(23,10) | NO   |     | 0.0000000000 |       |
| item_unit_price    | decimal(23,10) | NO   |     | 0.0000000000 |       |
| discount_percent   | int(11)        | NO   |     | 0            |       |
+--------------------+----------------+------+-----+--------------+-------+
9 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Query:

```
SELECT name, percent, cumulative, item_unit_price as price, quantity_purchased as quantity, discount_percent as discount 
FROM phppos_sales_items_taxes 
JOIN phppos_sales_items USING (sale_id, item_id, line) 
WHERE phppos_sales_items_taxes.sale_id = 2063 ORDER BY line,item_id,cumulative,name,percent
```

mysql 4 result: (Not sure the mode):

**1052 Column 'line' in order clause is ambiguous**

mysql 5 result:

**success...no error**

I actually understand why there is an error....but I want to know what specific behavior caused the query to be valid in mysql 5 but fail in mysql 4? Also, how can I have mysql 5 report this as an error too?

What table is line being ordered by in mysql 5?

Comment: I'm guessing the `order by line` bit. Try it in mysql 4 but make it `phppos_sales_items.line` instead (or the other table). Probably the parser in 4 wasn't smart enough to realize that `line` was used in the `using` clause, so it just sees two separate `line` fields in the joined tables and can't figure out which of the two you're intending to use.

Comment: What table does mysql 5 actually use for `line` (I am confused too)

Comment: You can check the chosen order by analysing the query result, right? MySql not realizing this ambiguity is probably a bug.

Comment: @Caffé both the fields have the same value always. I would think mysql did this on purpose. In mysql 5+ it doesn't result in an error. I agree I should be more specific, but I am just wondering what mysql is doing under the hood.

Comment: @MarcB I see it more as a bug than as smartness.

Comment: @Caffé I am not sure if it is a bug or a feature, but if I change from USING --> ON I get the same error as mysql 4. It seems USING must do something different. Either way I would just to be sure if this is a bug or a feature.

Comment: @Caffé I thought about it more and I see it as a feature. If you use the USING clause it means that the line columns are always going to be the same (by definition), so it isn't really a difference. If you use the ON clause it is ambiguous because you could join on any number of conditions that could result in different value. Either way I have changed the code so it will work in mysql 4. I would love to hear any other thoughts.

Comment: @ChrisMuench I see. Thanks to bring your analysis outcomes, Chris.